# node.js JSON.Strigify only values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Is there a way to JSON.Stringify only the values i.e. given the following JSON
`[{"id":6},{"id":24},{"id":46},{"id":12},{"id":29}]` get the following string:
`"6,24,46,12,29"` in a single line of code **without looping** over all the values like this

```
var valueStr = '';
for(let idx=0 idx < list.length; idx++){ valueStr += list[idx] + ',';}
//remove the last comma ...
```

Comment: You want to JSON stringify to a string that's _not JSON_?

Comment: You mean create an object with no named keys? Like a primitive array?

Comment: @suchislife I'm receiving a JSON from an API and wish to turn it into a string with no keys  just values separated by comma

Comment: Like CSV files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```js
const input = [{"id":6},{"id":24},{"id":46},{"id":12},{"id":29}];

const result = input.map(({ id }) => id).join(',');

console.log(result);
```